# ActionView::Template::Error: (translation missing: en.account.groups.reserve_and_funds)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I got following error while displaying view even I have cleared cache after installing plugin

ActionView::Template::Error (translation missing: en.account.groups.reserve_and_funds):
    157: 
    158: 
    159: 
    160: <% t('account.groups.reserve_and_funds') %>
    161: <% rf_ledger_ids = get_ledger_by_group(AccountGroup::AG_HASH['reserve_and_surplus']) %>
    162: <% rf_opening_balance = ledger_opening_balance(rf_ledger_ids) %>
    163: <% val_hash = get_hash_dccd(SystemConstant::DEBITRULE, SystemConstant::CREDITRULE, rf_ledger_ids, @from_date, @to_date)  %>
  app/views/spree/account/balance_sheets/_bal_sheet_cal.html.erb:160:in `_bbb75c09b5307b72b5249abc63b438b8'
  app/views/spree/account/balance_sheets/_bal_sheet.html.erb:1:in`_29ca1ef0f0b261e351539b4f61476d2b'
  app/views/spree/account/balance_sheets/_detail_view.html.erb:1:in `_a41aea51270c31de5e0cae0119590ea2'
  app/views/spree/account/balance_sheets/index.js.erb:2:in`_f5d021945ac0653007f63c2825ddeb1b'
  app/controllers/spree/account/balance_sheets_controller.rb:27:in `index'

Answer (score 1):

define in hierarchy as below in en.yml file

```
en: &en
  account:
    groups:
      reserve_and_funds: 'Reserve and funds'
```